# react-native-video example throws "TypeError:undefined" error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new with react native. I'm trying to make an app that has a youtube video embeded.I'm trying the example of this repo but it crashes on my project.

here is my full code. Crashes are comented where they are thrown. I dont understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using webstorm and I'm pretty sure that i've installed the package and linked it using thoose commands:

npm install --save react-native-video

react-native link react-native-video

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View>
              <Video source={{uri: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83mkGuGLNZg"}}
                 ref={(ref) => {
                   this.player = ref //Crash with TypeError:undefined is not an object
                 }}                                      // Store reference
                 onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                //Crash with TypeError:undefined is not an object
                 onError={this.videoError}               //Crash with TypeError:undefined is not an object
                 style={styles.backgroundVideo}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `this` statement. It refers to the function in which you are.

> When using strict mode, ‘this’ in a function will refer to it’s
>   explicit value, and if ‘this’ hasn’t been explicitly set then ‘this’
>   will be undefined.

So you have to `bind` it with `this.player=this.player.bind(this)`.

For further information you can look [here](https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480)

Comment: Hm, I think I understand what you say, but I dont know what I should do, and if I replace this.player = ref by your code it still breaks saying that this.player is undefined :/

Comment: Okey, but don't replace it. You can simply add this line at the beginning of your code (right after you declare the const App).